# Laravel Mixed Content: The page

Tags: php, laravel, ssl

за акцент извините
есть такой проблем на Ларавелу
пишет в консоле **Mixed Content: The page at '' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint ''. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.**
все урл там указанно через route('') or asset('');
на сайту установле SSL сертификат
AppServiceProvider тут писал это но не поможет

```
 Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
        if(config('app.env') === 'production') {
            \URL::forceScheme('https');
        }
```

Comment: переводите весь трафик автоматически на https через .htaccess

Comment: Так не получился :(

Answer (score 1):

Не указывай протокол в ajax-запросах. Все внутренние запросы посылай относительно корня сайта (`/some/my/endpoint`), а все запросы к другим доменам - с сохранением протокола (`//example.com/some/address`). Так же поступай с другими ресерсами на страницах (типа стилей, скритпов, картинок, картинок в стилях).